# Change photo on Google sign in page

Tags: google-account

On the Google sign in page - where you can choose which identity you want to sign in as if you have more than one, my old photos still appear.

I have altered on my profile and in Google+ but the sign in page still persists in showing my old ones.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it’s just the image cache. You can clear the browser’s cache. Or try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> if you are on a Mac, when you are on that page.